# Get latest revision number of a file from cvs repository

Tags: version-control, cvs

Is there a way to know the latest revision number of a file in cvs repository without checking out that file.

The exact problem is, suppose I know the name of a file which is in cvs repo. Let's call it file1.text.

So, is there any command or any way by which I can search repo for that file and get the latest revision number of that file?

Comment: Are you using branches?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CVS log and give a revision as "starting point":

```
$ cvs log -r{REVISION}:: file1.text
```

The `-r{REVISION}::` will only search for revisions after `{REVISION}` (can be a number or tag).

If you don't have a working copy, you can use `rls` cvs command. With `-l` argument, it will print the version of files.

```
$ cvs rls -l MyModule/path/to/the/file
```

You can use `-r` to specify a branch.

Comment: But for that you need to have the checked out file1.text.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had a working copy. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command to use:

> cvs history -a -c -l module/file1.text

This will display the version and the date the file was last modified. This doesn't require the module or file checked out.